# cant start osgi bundle because import cannot be resolved

Tags: java, maven, osgi, bundle

I have made a small API Bundle and a service bundle that should use the API.

In my maven pom.xml file, i added a dependecy for my api bundle in the correct version like this:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>at.foobar.osgi.api</groupId>
  <artifactId>foobarapi</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

i'm using the maven-bundle plugin to create the bundles, and because of that i used `mvn clean install` to create by jar file.
The Manifest looks like this (the service):

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Private-Package: at.foobar.osgi.producer
Built-By: foobar
Tool: Bnd-0.0.238
Bundle-Name: foobarproducer
Created-By: Apache Maven Bundle Plugin
Bundle-Version: 1.0
Build-Jdk: 1.6.0_26
Bnd-LastModified: 1332185439257
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Activator: at.foobar.osgi.producer.Activator
Import-Package: at.foobar.osgi.api,org.osgi.framework;version="1.4"
Bundle-SymbolicName: at.foobar.osgi.producer.foobarproducer
```

which seems to be OK for me. The import is in there, so everything should be fine.

now i started up equinox and installed the API and the producer bundle.
Then i startet the API, which worked out fine. But when i want to start the Producer Service i get this error:

```
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The bundle "at.foobar.osgi.producer.foobarproducer_1.0.0 [4]" could not be resolved. Reason: Missing Constraint: Import-Package: at.foobar.osgi.api; version="0.0.0"
```

It seems that the framework cannot find the api, but its installed and started?

Comment: Have you fired up the equinox console and run 'packages at.foobar.osgi.api' to confirm that package is exported by your API bundle? If you get a huge scrolling list of packages, that means no bundle exports that package. I'd also try 'bundle [api-bundle-name]' to see which packages the API bundle does export - and confirm it itself is started.

Comment: mh i forgot to export the API... but what i dont understand why i need to export it? I read the Core spec and thought that the API package should not be exported because its resolved by osgi?

Comment: The package needs to be either exported by your bundle OR included in the bundle (i.e. listed ir Private-Package). You have done neither, therefore Bnd detects it as an Imported package. Probably Export is correct because it sounds like an API that other bundles may want to use.

Comment: Regarding your question "the API package should not be exported because its resolved by osgi"... this means nothing to me. Could you clarify what you expected to happen?

Comment: @NeilBartlett: ah ok now i understand, thats exactly the question i asked in my comment!

Comment: @reox May be you post an answer to remove this question from ununswered?

Comment: @Alex this is still unanswered, i did something back Athen and it worked but i cant reproduce it... Maybe it was a build problem

Answer (score 9):

Make sure that you are exporting the API packages, so that your service bundle can bind to them.

In your maven-bundle-plugin for the API bundle you should have something like:

```
            <configuration>
                <instructions>
                    <Import-Package>
                        *
                    </Import-Package>
                    <Export-Package>
                        at.foobar.osgi.api.*
                    </Export-Package>
                </instructions>
            </configuration>
```

Comment: dude you have just saved me from becoming an alcoholic. thank you so very very much!